# Event for control within XML fragment is not triggered

Tags: sapui5

I've created an xml-fragment for my Javascript view. In the view controller I create my instance of the fragment via `sap.ui.xmlfragment('myapp.popover')` and display it. In the popover I have a `sap.m.List` with an `sap.m.ActionListItem` which I define with `<ActionListItem press="test"/>`. The controller function is defined with

```
test: function(e) {
    console.log("test");
},
```

But the controller function is never called. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event handlers from XML fragment not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534777/event-handlers-from-xml-fragment-not-triggered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML fragment instantiation requires `Controller` to be used for event handlers in the Fragment.

```
sap.ui.xmlfragment('myapp.popover', this);
```

`this` will be context of controller in which you are creating fragment.